# how to give alternating class to alternating item of @foreach look in Razor + umbraco

Tags: razor, umbraco, razor-2, umbraco7, umbraco6

I am using Umbraco 7.x

I need some thing like following In list Item generated using for each. alternating item need to give respective class.

[image]

So is their any was to determine even and odd row to give respective class name.

As following is my code for the same.

```
@foreach (var itemTblRows in @Model.Children) 
        {       
         <tr class="light">
                <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData1</td>
                <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData2</td>
                <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData3</td>
                <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData4</td>
              </tr>
        }
```

I will not like to use CSS and JS to do so, because in other case (with diff. lay out) it will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do easily with the `IsOdd` and `IsEven` helper methods:

```
<tr class="@itemTblRows.IsOdd("odd","even")>
```

or

```
<tr class="@itemTblRows.IsEven("even","odd")>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple CSS only approach to accomplishing the result you're looking for.  First, add a class to the table these rows belong to:

```
<table class="striped">
@foreach (var itemTblRows in @Model.Children) 
{       
   <tr>
        <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData1</td>
        <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData2</td>
        <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData3</td>
        <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData4</td>
   </tr>
}
</table>
```

Then add in these CSS rules:

```
table.striped tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: grey; }
table.striped tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: white; }
```

Then you add in your CSS as needed.  The nth-child(*n*) selector allows you to select every *n*th child that is a match. Specifying odd or even allows you take select every odd child, or every even child.

Answer (score 1):

Create a counter variable c which you will increment in each loop.  In each loop perform a modulus (%) using 2 as the denominator.  If the result is greater than 0 then it is ***odd*** otherwise ***even***

```
    var c = 1;
    @foreach (var itemTblRows in @Model.Children)
    {
        var oddEvenClass = c % 2 > 0 ? "odd" : "even";
        c += 1;
        <tr class="light @oddEvenClass">
            <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData1</td>
            <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData2</td>
            <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData3</td>
            <td>@itemTblRows.ABL_tableData4</td>
        </tr>
    }
```